# Need to get the value of the adjacent checkboxes

Tags: jquery, checkbox, each

I click on the checkbox and I should come about all checkboxes on row, checked or not (3 checkbox).

[image]
When I click on the checkbox `update_order_status(this);`

```
function update_order_status(e){
    var order_id = $(e).parents('tr').find('.order_id').html();
    var status_id = $(e).parents('tr').find('.status_id').val();

    $(e).parents('tr').find('input').each(function(i){
        //watch all input on the page, but not row
    });
}
```

Comment: @ManjunathManohar "Your post does not have much context to explain the code sections; please explain your scenario more clearly."

I write, but do not save

Comment: what is the question? what part is not working... you haven't explained much about the situation, or provided much code (js or html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the closest method. inside your checkbox method

```
function yourMethod(e){
  $(e).closest("tr").find(':checkbox').each(function(e2){
    // code
  });
}
```

The closest method selects the most closest dom element up the tree and stops when finding it, So it will select only the parent tr.

Comment: Only that he realized works. I tried, but I forgot that the page has disabled scripts, and thought "closest" does not work.

Comment: Alright buddy. If you had posted the html structure it would have been much more clearer and answer would have been faster. :)

Comment: Excuse me, will add to the next time :)

Answer (score 0):

You must call checkbox parents first row, and use this instead e:

```
$(':checkbox').click(function(e){
    $(this).parents("tr:first").find(':checkbox').each(function(e2){
         //Required logic here
    });
});
```